# jQueryUI drop on target closest to mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQueryUI's draggable and droppable interactions, and in my application I only want to allow a draggable to be dropped into a single drop target, ideally the target that is closest to the mouse, or the target that has the most overlap with the draggable. The problem is that my drop targets can sometimes be close together, and it is very possible that a draggable will overlap more than one drop target. When my draggable overlaps more than one drop target, I'd like to set the hoverClass on only one of the drop targets, and only allow the drop on that target. Is this possible with jQueryUI?

I like the behavior of the 'touch' tolerance, so I'd like to keep that if possible. Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem I'm trying to solve:
http://jsfiddle.net/gDkAQ/2/

```
$('.draggable').draggable();

$('.droppable').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    hoverClass: 'drop-acceptable',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css({ 'background-color': '#00f' });
    }
});
```

There is another library from [ThreeDubMedia](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop) that provides the exact feature I'm looking for (the "overlap" tolerance mode), but unfortunately that library only seems to work with absolute-positioned elements, so I don't think it would work in my application.

Comment: you can use position().top with respect to your drag element and you can highlight the closest one this simple idea you can try

Comment: The trick is somehow accessing the "other" drop targets beneath my draggable, to determine which of them is the closest. jQueryUI doesn't seem to expose a list of the drop targets.

Comment: i did not get your comment Marc (".droppable").each() will give you the complete list

Comment: You've given me an idea, I can use my hoverClass to access all of the drop targets currently under my draggable. I now have working code that identifies the closest drop target, next I just need to figure out how to deactivate the drop targets that are not the closest. I'm close! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with a solution, but it involves fragile duck punching of jQueryUI. There is an internal function called `$.ui.intersect` that determines if a draggable can be dropped onto a droppable. There is also a `$.ui.ddmanager.droppables` collection that contains a list of all droppables on the page. I overrode the `intersect` function to support a 'touch-closest-to-mouse' toleranceMode that finds the closest droppable to the mouse, and only returns true if the current droppable is the closest. Here is the solution I came up with:

```
(function () {
    var defaultIntersect = $.ui.intersect;
    var cursorX, cursorY;

    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        cursorX = e.pageX;
        cursorY = e.pageY;
    });

    $.ui.intersect = function (draggable, droppable, toleranceMode) {
        if (toleranceMode !== 'touch-closest-to-mouse') {
            return defaultIntersect(draggable, droppable, toleranceMode);
        }
        if (!defaultIntersect(draggable, droppable, 'touch')) {
            return false;
        }
        var acceptable = _.filter($.ui.ddmanager.droppables.default, function (d) {
            return defaultIntersect(draggable, d, 'touch');
        });
        var closest = _.min(acceptable, function (other) {
            var otherCenterX = other.offset.left + other.proportions().width / 2;
            var otherCenterY = other.offset.top + other.proportions().height / 2;
            return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(otherCenterX - cursorX, 2) + Math.pow(otherCenterY - cursorY, 2));
        });
        return droppable === closest;
    };

    $('.draggable').draggable();

    $('.droppable').droppable({
        tolerance: 'touch-closest-to-mouse',
        hoverClass: 'drop-acceptable',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(event.target).css({
                'background-color': '#0f0'
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

This works with jQueryUI 1.10.4. Here is a jsfiddle with the working solution: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gDkAQ/12/